# $r(n)$ is the sum of the remainders when $n$ is divided by $1,2...,n$ ...

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

For a positive interger $n$, let $r(n)$ be the sum of the remainders when $n$ is divided by $1,2, \ldots ,n$ respectively. Prove that $r(k)=r(k+1)$ for infinitely many positive intergers $k$.

Here's my try:

By the division algorithm we have $a=bq+r$ and $a-bq=r$. So $r(k)= k(k-1)-(2q_2 + 3q_3+ \ldots kq_k$) and $r(k+1)= (k-1)(k+1) -(2p_2 + 3p_3+ \ldots kp_k$) where $q_i = \lfloor \frac {k}{i} \rfloor$ and $p_i= \lfloor \frac {k+1}{i} \rfloor$

So if $r(k)=r(k+1)$ then $0= k-1 -( 2(p_2-q_2)+ 3(p_3-q_3) \ldots + k(p_k - q_k))$ and I think that $p_n-q_n$ can be equal to $0$ or $1$ depending on if $k+1$ is or is not divisible by $n$. I don't know if my last claim is correct but I think it is.

I would like to receive any hints or help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: Use your favourite programming language to calculate and output the values of $r(k)$ up to 100. Find the instances where $r(k)=r(k+1)$. A pattern should emerge and you can possibly formulate a conjecture for an infinite sequence of such occurances, then try to prove that conjecture.

Comment: I don't know much about programming

Comment: Then do it by hand until $k=10$. You should find 3 values, maybe that is enough to start the conjecture.
I can give you the solution outright, if you want.

Comment: I found that $r(2^k)=r(2^k-1)$ for $k=1,2$ and $3$, but couldn't deduce anything else.

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind. It's true for all $k$. You can use your formula for the difference $r(k+1)-r(k)$, with $p_n-q_n \in \{0,1\}$ when you take into account the divisibility condition, which is easy to handle for $k+1=2^m$. There is however a small error in your formula, you have forgotten the term $(k+1)p_{k+1}=k+1$ in $r(k+1)$. If you need more tips, say so.

Comment: I excluded that on purpose, I think I should have put $k-1$ instead of $2k$.

Comment: Right, that's the same formula I got.

Comment: It's obvious that one possible value of $k$ are of the form of $2^k-1$ but are those the only possible cases? I think this problem reduces to find a number $n$ s.t the sum of its divisors is equal to $n-1$  .

Comment: Yes, I got the same deduction. Numerical tests showed no other solutions $< 2^{18}$. Maybe if you search for 'sum of divisors' on this site, you may be able to find something.